# How exactly do I add a variable to another variable after a switch statement

Tags: c++

I apologize in an advance, as I could not find better wording for the question I have to ask, so I might as well explain it in here. I recently got the book C++ How to program 9th edition and I have been practicing and I am in the 5th chapter. My problem is, is that in my code I am having trouble adding a total to another variable while in a while loop. Basically I am getting returned 0 every time and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Would anyone care to shed some light on the situation and explain to me what I can do better for next time? I mean the code itself runs fine with no errors, but I am just having trouble with that calculation!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int selection = 0;
    float total = 0.0;
    float lastTotal = 0.0;
    float product1 = 2.98;
    float product2 = 4.50;
    float product3 = 9.98;
    float product4 = 4.49;
    float product5 = 6.87;
    bool loop = true;

    while (loop == true)
    {
        cout << "Please make a selection from the following items and when you are done buying (-1) the products I will display your total\n" << endl;
        cout << "1: $" << product1 << endl;
        cout << "2: $" << product2 << endl;
        cout << "3: $" << product3 << endl;
        cout << "4: $" << product4 << endl;
        cout << "5: $" << product5 << endl << endl;

        total += lastTotal;

        cin >> selection;
        cout << "\n";

        switch (selection)
        {

            case 1:
                cout << "You have selected Product 1 which costs $2.98\n" << endl;
                total = product1;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "You have selected Product 2 which costs $4.50\n" << endl;
                total = product2;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "You have selected Product 3 which costs $9.98\n" << endl;
                total = product3;
                break;

            case 4:
                cout << "You have selected Product 4 which costs $4.49\n" << endl;
                total = product4;
                break;

            case 5:
                cout << "You have selected Product 5 which costs $6.87\n" << endl;
                total = product5;
                break;

            case -1:
                cout << "Thank you. Your total is: " << lastTotal << endl;
                loop = false;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;            
        }       
    }
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp:6:11: error: '::main' must return 'int'
 void main()
           ^
```

Also as a side note. What exactly are the warnings meaning? I don't see them crashing my code, but it concerns me when they pop up when I run it.

Comment: This is where you should be using the debugger.  It should be interesting to you that the program terminates.  What lines in your code can cause the program to terminate?  Why would you reach that line?

Comment: @dodexahedron Hey. That is another thing, is I am having trouble with the debugger. I put the breakpoint at the start of the while loop and click debug and run. What I have noticed is that total does get saved in the switch statement, but as soon as I want to save total into the other variable it just outputs 0 and I am not sure why

Comment: warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'float' I get that warning 4 times everytime I run, but I am not worried about that at the moment, that is another thing to worry about.

Comment: For your float warnings, literal floating points (`1.0`, `2.98`, etc..)  are type `double`. Tack a `f` on the end, `2.98f`, if you want `float` literals.

Comment: Bah. I wish people hadn't just given the answer, but yes - the issue is that you're not setting the value that you're trying to output, at all.

Comment: The error is because you have no return statement.

Comment: Oh! That makes so much more sense. You see there was one way I was taught at the beginning and it was to use void, thank you very much

Comment: Find the guy that taught you that and print him a nice copy of the relevant portion of the language standard., C++11 § 3.6.1 [basic.start.main],p3 : "An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall have a return type of type int**"

Comment: @WhozCraig It was actually my college professor that did. He told us we could use both if we wanted to. I guess since it was the beginner course he wanted to use that instead? But I have to say as a side note I am really enjoying programming. I personally love trying to solve problems by myself for long periods of times, but it was getting pretty late where I am and I didn't want to sleep until it was solved if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Glorpy for a real noodle-baker you can also mention this to your prof:  `main()` must be declared to return `int` per the standard. But it also doesn't have to actually `return` anything in its body. If no `return` is provided, the effect is that of executing `return 0;` upon leaving the `main()` function.

Comment: @WhozCraig Alright, will do! Thanks for the tip. Just one other thing. It is not really big, more of a nitpicky thing. You see if you put my program into Visual Studio and you run it you will see when asked to enter product 2 it will say 4.5 instead of 4.50. It refuses to show that 0 on the 4.50. I also changed the thing to int main() with return 0 at the very end before the last curly brace

Comment: A combination of [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) are likely what you're looking for. They in `<iomanip>` and can be used to modify how your output is formed. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks again for your help. Take care friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use lastTotal and total. Just using total does the job. lastTotal is never assigned or changed!

```
cout << "Thank you. Your total is: " << lastTotal << endl;
```

change to:

```
cout << "Thank you. Your total is: " << total << endl;
```

total is fine. but you are showing the lastTotal.

For the error, modify the code as folowing:

```
int main()
{
    ....

    return 0;
}
```

main must be int!

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why I was stumped on this for so long when the answer was just right there. You see I have been at this for about 2 hours just trying different things. I used this as a last resort so thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 2):

To add a value to total you assign the sum to the total.

```
total = total+value
```

The standard says that main funtion should return int

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
total = product1;
```

This line sets the total to `product1`. It does not add `product1` to the total.

As usual, the computer is doing exactly what you told it to do, and overwriting `total` with the value of `product1`. A similar thing happens with products 2, 3, 4 and 5.